Error uploading file: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
const ImgHash = `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${resFile.data.IpfsHash}`;
                
// Correcting the contract call
await contract.add(account, ImgHash);
                
alert("Successfully uploaded image");
setFileName("No image uploaded");
setFile(null);

Here’s the Solidity code for the function add():
function add(address _user, string calldata url) external {
    values[_user].push(url);
}


It should be
// Correcting the contract call
contract.methods.add(parameters).send({ from: account, gas: 3000000 })

You forgot to include methods.
Also this is a state changing call you have to have the .send() method to send where the call is coming from and how much gas do you want to spend.
Alternatively, encode your function call and then send the transaction seperately.
    const data = contract.methods.add(account, ImgHash).encodeABI(); 

    const tx = {
        from: account,
        to: contractAdress,
        gas: 3000000,
        data: data
    };
        const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
        console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);

https://docs.web3js.org/libdocs/Contract/
